# How to update a combobox bound in a listbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection, and inside the ListBox.ItemTemplate I have a ComboBox bound to another ObservableCollection.

What I need is to update those ComboBoxes after saving the ListBox data.

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding KeyValues, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="4" Margin="0,1,1,1" Background="#EEE">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,1">Value</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,1" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,1">Combo 1</Label>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,1" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Combo1}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableKeyValues, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and here the properties in the c# code:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValue> _KeyValues = null;
public ObservableCollection<KeyValue> KeyValues
{
    get
    {
        if (_KeyValues == null)
        {
            // _KeyValues = ... (Database call)
        }
        return _KeyValues;
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<KeyValue> _SelectableKeyValues = null;
public ObservableCollection<KeyValue> SelectableKeyValues
{
    get
    {
        if (_SelectableKeyValues == null)
        {
            // _SelectableKeyValues = ... (Database call)
        }
        return _SelectableKeyValues;
    }
}
```

an the method called after saving:

```
public void RefreshData()
{
    listBox.Items.Refresh();
    _SelectableKeyValues = null;
}
```

I have tried also to manually reload that collection but the result is always the same:

in the ComboBox I never find the new elements (which I am sure there are)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a quick tip, set Mode=TwoWay on your combobox itemsource binding

Comment: doesn't work, since it's a read-only property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your UserControl (the class that contains SelectableKeyValues definition) and inside RefreshData method raise PropertyChanged event with "SelectableKeyValues" as event arguments constructor parameter.
using ObservableCollection doesnt help you in this case because you doesnt change collection but replace it. 
let us know if you need code examples

Comment: perfect! thanks, I didn't know a UserControl has an "already handled" propertychanged